# how a transaction is confirmed after all block are mined (newbie)

Tags: ethereum-classic, bitcoin

I'm completely a newbie in crypto currency. There is a question stuck in my head:
Fact:
- when an amount is sent from me to someone then a transaction is created and broadcasted on network.
- this transaction must be included in a block to be mined by a miner to create a NEW BLOCK (then its state becomes "confirmed")
Question:
- When all block are mined in far future (e.g: 21 mil blocks for bitcoin). Then there is no NEW BLOCK to be mined then How transaction is confirmed then?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum has no limit on the number of blocks that will be produced nor the number of coins that can be given as rewards to miners.

Bitcoin doesn't have a limit to the number of blocks that will be produced either. It does, however, have a limit on the number of coins that will exist (21 million). Like Ethereum, though, Bitcoin's miners are rewarded both in new coins as well as transaction fees. Even after the block reward stops (when no more coins can be created), the transaction fee will remain as the miners' incentive. The transaction fee will likely go up to cover the lack of a block reward.

See https://99bitcoins.com/what-will-happen-when-all-bitcoins-are-mined/.

Comment: Thanks! as you said "it does, however, have a limit on the number of coins that will exist (21 million)" . the number of 21 million is defined somewhere in the code of bitcoin-core?

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be specified in the genesis block?